# Solving for an expected value from discrete random variables

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble seeing where I'm going wrong with a problem.  The is the question:

An urn contains 30 marbles of which 8 are black, 12 are red, and 10 are blue.  Randomly, select four marbles without replacement.  Let X be the number of black marbles in the sample of four.

- a. What is the probability that no black marble was selected?
- b. What is the probability that exactly one black marble was selected?
- c. Compute E(X).

I've solved a and b as follows:

- a. 
  $\displaystyle {{8!\over 0!(8-0)!}\cdot{22!\over 4!(22-4)!} \over {30!\over 4!(30-4)!}}$
  so basically, ${22*21*20*19 \over 30*29*28*27}$
  ->
  approximately $0.267$
- b.
  similarly,
  $\displaystyle{{8!\over 1!(8-1)!}{22!\over 3!(22-3)!}\over {30!\over 4!(30-4)!}}$
  ->
  approximately $0.449$

Right now, I'm trying to solve for E(X), which from what I think I understand is the total expected outcome of every way a black marble would be drawn...

so it would be E(X)=(0 drawn)+(1 drawn)+(2 drawn)+(3 drawn)+(4 drawn)

I've continued to solve in the same format as the previous questions for the last three possibilities of a black marble being drawn, and I get an answer of 
1.058.

The correct answer should be 1.067.

Am I making a simple calculation error, or is my understanding of how to solve for the expected value completely wrong from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is indeed $1.067$.  I can't say *how* you are wrong without seeing what you've done.  But the easy way is to utilise Linearity of Expectation and indicator random variables.

$\mathsf E(X)$ is the expected number of black marbles in a sample of 4 marbles, which is drawn without replacement from a population of 30 containing 8 black marbles.

We consider that the drawn marbles can be placed in a line, and on doing so let $X_i$ be the *indicator* that the $i$-th marble in this line is black.   The probability that a particular marble in the line will be black is: $8/30$.   Thus $\mathsf E(X_i)=8/30$ for all four marbles.

By the Linearity of Expectation then: $\mathsf E(X) $ $= \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 \mathsf E(X_i) \\[2ex] = 16/15$

---

Alternatively we note that $\mathsf P(X=x) = \dfrac{\dbinom{8}{x}\dbinom{22}{4-x}}{\dbinom{30}{4}} = \cfrac{\cfrac{8!}{x!(8-x)!}\cfrac{22!}{(4-x)!(18+x)!}}{\cfrac{30!}{4!26!}}$ .

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) & = \sum_{x=0}^4 x\;\mathsf P(X{=}x) \\[2ex] & = 0+\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{1}\dbinom{22}{3}}{\dbinom{30}{4}} + \dfrac{2\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{22}{2}}{\dbinom{30}{4}} + \dfrac{3\dbinom{8}{3}\dbinom{22}{1}}{\dbinom{30}{4}}+ \dfrac{4\dbinom{8}{4}\dbinom{22}{0}}{\dbinom{30}{4}}\end{align}$$

Crunching the numbers should give the same result, and if it doesn't you have indeed made a calculation error.  (Or a typo, and we're all capable of making won.)

Comment: I believe that I have the general format correct, (I didn't use the correct term when I said probability) but the two places that I have erred are...1.multiplying each corresponding drawing with exactly how many black marbles are drawn (which I don't quite understand why that should be done) and 2. I have 30!/4!(30-4!) versus 8!...I used 4 because out of thirty, there are 4 random drawings...I don't understand why 9 is taken from 8 marbles.  Also, sorry for the format of my numbers, I'm not sure how to type them in a more legible format.  I'm new to this website

Comment: @AnnLee Expected Value is a weighted average (know as *the mean*).  For a discrete random variable, such as this one, it's the sum of all the products of the values and their probabilities. Hence: $$\mathsf E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^4 k\;\mathsf P(X=k)$$

Comment: For example, take a fair six sided die and roll.  The expected value of the result, the mean result, or the average of the numbers thrown, is: $3.5$. $$1\times\tfrac 1 6 + 2\times \tfrac 1 6 + 3\times \tfrac 1 6 +4\times \tfrac 1 6 +5\times \tfrac 1 6 +6\times \tfrac 1 6 = \tfrac 7 2$$Of course, if the die were biased, those probabilities would not all be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for parts (a) and (b) looks correct.

The formula for expected value should be:

$E(X)=0*($probability 0 drawn$) + 1*($probability 1 drawn$) + 2*($probability 2 drawn$) + 3*($probability 3 drawn$) + 4*($probability 4 drawn$)$

Note that, of course, you can drop the first term as it is a product of zero, but I thought including it makes the formula more intuitive. It looks like to forgot to multiply each of the probabilities in the formula by 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively.

Since you already calculated the probabilities, why don't you plug in the numbers and see what you get?

Comment: Nah; just summing the probabilities should give $1$.  Looks like some of them were miscalculated.

Comment: I don't get the correct answer...and looking at the other response to my query, I think there it's because I am understanding the the combination formula to be 30 with drawing 4 marbles, but for some reason it should be 8 because it choosing from 8 black marbles...I'm supposing...also, why is each probability multiplied by the number corresponding to how many black marbles are drawn exactly?

Comment: If you think of the expected value as a weighted average, multiplying by the number of black marbles you get makes sense. If you were to repeat this experiment (drawing four marbles and counting how many are black), you would get 0 black marbles ~26.7% of the time, 1 black marble ~45.0% of the time, 2 black marbles ~23.6% of the time, 3 black marbles ~4.5% of the time and 4 black marbles ~0.3% of the time. If you want to know the number of marbles that you draw, on average, you would combine the numbers in the way prescribed by the expected value formula.

Comment: For example, if you repeat the experiment 1000 times, you would (expect to) draw 1 black marble 450 times, 2 black marbles 236 times, etc. To get the average number of blacks marbles drawn per experiment, you do $1*450 + 2*236 + 3*45 + 4*3$ then divide by 1000 to get 1.069. We are still off by .002, but this is due to rounding off.